# get ip address from url

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to get country location from the ip address which I am also looking up from actual url. However for certain urls I am getting the following error:

> The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for

I wanted to use the following code to identify the proxy perhaps but since this is a regular console app I am not sure how to get around it. Here is my code;

```
For Each prod In querylist
    If myfetcher.getHtml(prod, userAgent, page) Then
      ' The lines below I use to find proxy ip
      ' but error name 'Request' not declared
        ' Dim nowip As String
        ' nowip = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
        ' If nowip = "" Then
        'nowip = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
        'End If
        '

        If prod.Contains("http://") Then
            prod = Regex.Replace(prod, "http://", "")
        End If
        badHost = prod
        Dim ipEntry As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(prod)
        Dim IPAdd As IPAddress() = ipEntry.AddressList
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To IPAdd.GetUpperBound(0)
            number = number & "IP Address {0}:{1}" & IPAdd(i).ToString
        Next
        IPList.Add(prod & " " & number)
        number = ""
    Else
        badList.Add(prod)
        number = ""
    End If
    count = count + 1
Next
```

Comment: You're stripping off the http from the URL but not the page path - are you passing `stackoverflow.com/questions/3813747/` into the DNS call? You just want the `stackoverflow.com` part. You can use the System.Uri class to parse the domain out of URLs.

Comment: This is examples of the urls that gave the error www.edresearch.co.jp,

Comment: so I think u r saying that the www. should not be in there and the other url was something like hhhh.com.cn so I removed the .com part and that helped. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a language agnostic way to do it:

do a HTTP GET for

```
domain2ip.net/:url
```

like

```
http://domain2ip.net/www.edresearch.co.jp
```

is

```
122.200.237.66
```

you can even to it from JavaScript

```
 $.getJSON("http://domain2ip.net/google.com", callback);
```

---

Disclosure: it's my site, and open source.